# Dependent in 2019 and 2020 but not in 2018. Stimulus received. Does it have to be returned

Tags: united-states, dependents, covid-19, stimulus

An individidual was not a dependent in 2018. She is in 2019 and 2020, but she received her stimulus funds before 2019 taxes were filed. Is she required to return the funds?